# Has to click "Submit" button twice for submitting form

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using jsf/promefaces in my application. I have a form with multiple input components, in which 2 input components are PrimaryKey values. So, as soon as user enters the PK values, the "ValueChange" ajax event fires and validation check for duplicate PK happens.
      If there are only PK input components in the form, So when user enters value in the inputtext and clicks the Submit button(Focus is still with InputText), then InputText's value change listener is called but not Submit buttons action. For this reason I need to click the Submit button twice.
      Is there any approach to overcome this or way to queue the ajax calls.Code given below.

```
 <p:outputLabel value="selectOneLabel" for="selectOne" /> 
 <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOne" value="#{bean.selectOne}" required="true" >
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectOneList}" />
   <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.validatePK()}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>

 <p:outputLabel value="inputTextLabel" for="input" />
 <p:inputText id="inputText"  value="#{bean.inputText}" required="true">
   <p:ajax listener="#{bean.validatePK()}"/>
 </p:inputText>

 <p:commandButton id="submit" action="#{bean.CreateAction()}" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it:

Input:

```
<p:inputText value="#{value}">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this error_msg" partialSubmit="true"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="validatorID"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Button:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" 
                 action="#{controller.save()}"
                 process="@all"
                 update="@all"
                 partialSubmit="false"
/>
```

This works like a charm ;) Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks Mo, actually I have number of ui pages in which data is displayed from differntof tables, So I can't just write one validate method to validate PrimaryKey Constraint in differnt tables.

Comment: Ofcause you will need a different validator for every PK then. But that should not be too difficult to change the validator as needed ;)